# Error when I try to read a file using Capacitor in Android 11

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have an app using Ionic and Capacitor with target API 29, but I need to change to API 30 because of PlayStore rules.

My problem with this transition is with capacitor filesystem, which is not finding files in my device. I need to read these files to import in the map in my app.

I tried to read files and directories, tried to create some random files and use stat to get files information, but sometimes I can read these files and sometimes I don't. I tried to find a pattern in this errors with some tests, but I couldn't find or understand the pattern.

Initially I thought that this problem was caused by external storage permissions, so I added in the manifest the relevant parameters, even so the errors persisted in my app. I started to think that this can be related to [Android Unix Permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File-system_permissions), but I can't say if that is true. I tried to use `checkPermissions()` of Capacitor, but I received the 'granted' response.

External Storage parameters in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I tried to research for permission problems related to capacitor filesystem, but the only question I found is [my own](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/capacitor-filesystem-error-when-i-try-to-read-a-file-in-android-11/211101) about the same subject, created a while ago. This question have an answer, but it is but not applicable for API 30.
I also tried to research about filesystem android permissions too, I found one [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/208906/is-it-possible-to-change-file-permissions-on-androids-internal-storage/208927#208927) about this subject, but this only tell me that I can't modify the FS permission properties.

Some things I tried to do:

First I tried to use [`readFile()`](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem#readfile) in a file on external storage:

```
this.fs.readFile('Download/test.kml', true).then(response => {
  console.log(response)
});
```

`readFile()` function inside FS service:

```
/** Read a file and returns a string as base 64 */
readFile(path: string, needDirectory: boolean = false, dir: string = 'ExternalStorage'): Promise<string> {
    let options: ReadFileOptions;
    if (needDirectory) {
        options = {
            path: path,
            directory: Directory[dir]
        }
    } else {
        options = {
            path: path
        }
    }

    return Filesystem.readFile(options).then(result => {
        return result.data;
    });
}
```

But it didn't work, then I tried to create some files using [`writeFile()`](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem#writefile), in tree different directories:

```
this.fs.writeFile('Download/', 'test.kml', "<xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'></xml>", true, undefined, true);
this.fs.writeFile('/', 'test.kml', "<xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'></xml>", true, 'External', true);
this.fs.writeFile('/', 'test.kml', "<xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'></xml>", true, 'Documents', true);
```

`writeFile()` function inside FS service:

```
/** Write a file, content in base64, Pass encoding to true to write data as string */
writeFile(path: string, filename: string, content: any, recursive: boolean = false, dir: string = 'ExternalStorage', encoding: boolean = false): Promise<boolean> {
    let options: WriteFileOptions = {
        path: path + filename,
        data: content,
        directory: Directory[dir],
        recursive: recursive
    }
    if (encoding) {
        options.encoding = Encoding.UTF8
    }
    
    return Filesystem.writeFile(options).then(result => {
        if (result) {
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    })
}
```

This worked! Then I tried to read all these newly created files:

```
this.fs.readFile('Download/test.kml', true);
this.fs.readFile('test.kml', true, 'External');
this.fs.readFile('test.kml', true, 'Documents');
```

This worked too!, Now, in my head the problem is with the files that aren't created by my app, but the files that already exist in FS or are moved by the user. So I tried to use [`readDir`](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem#readdir) to test what the app sees:

```
this.fs.readDir('/', undefined, true)
this.fs.readDir('/', 'External', true)
this.fs.readDir('/', 'Documents', true)
```

`readDir` function into de fs service:

```
/** Read dir and list this files */
readDir(path: string, dir: string = 'ExternalStorage', needDirectory: boolean = true): Promise<ReaddirResult> {
    let options: ReaddirOptions;
    if (needDirectory) {
        options = {
            path: path,
            directory: Directory[dir]
        }
    } else {
        options = {
            path: path
        }
    }
    return Filesystem.readdir(options).then(files => {
        return files;
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
        let resultError: ReaddirResult = {
            files: []
        };
        return resultError;
    })
}
```

The `readDir()` returns me only the folders that my app created, but there are others files in this directory, those that were created manually didn't appear. Then I tried to use the [`stat()`](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem#stat) function in one of this files that my app didn't saw:

```
this.fs.getStat('USO.kml', 'Documents')
this.fs.getStat('USO.kml')
```

`getStat()` function inside FS service:

```
/** 
 * Get file information's: type, size, ctime(Create time), mtime(Last modification), uri
 * @param path path of file
 * @param dir directory where is file
*/
getStat(path: string, dir: string = 'ExternalStorage'): Promise<StatResult> {
    return Filesystem.stat({
        path: path,
        directory: Directory[dir]
    }).then(result => {
        return result;
    });
}
```

I can't understand, because the file `USO.kml` in Documents directory appear in stat function, but another one in external storage returns me an error `File does not exist`. I don't understand why it's happening. How can I correctly read the files using Capacitor FS and API 30?

## Edit

Just to clarify: The file is moved externally by the user and saved inside this directory through Android explorer. I need to import this file to my app to get the information inside.

Comment: `this.fs.readFile('Download/test.kml'` Who put that file in that directory? Your app? If not then your app has no acces to that file on an Android 11+ device as the owner of the file is important on Android 11 devices. Further that is not a full path but a relative path. I dont know what Capacitor asks but a full path would be `/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.kml`.

Comment: The file is moved externally by the user and saved inside this directory through Android explorer. I need to import this file to my app to get the information inside. This is indeed the directory, but when using Capacitor I don't need to pass the full path, I can use the option "Directory" inside the options object and the API complete the uri by itself.

Comment: Read about android 11 scoped storage. You simply don’t have access to the downloads folder anymore.

Comment: I believe I'm not the only one with an app that involves importing FS files from the device. Even if it's not in the download or documents folder, I would like to know if there is somewhere I can access and import this file, even if I have to leave a message for the user that he needs to place  the file in that specific location.

Comment: You have to use SAF to let the user choose the file.

Comment: I had a similar problem. The solution (for me) was to use a file picker plugin, which can read the file data directly, because the plugin has all the necessary rights at this time.